# Could not fetch URL ImportXML Google Sheets - https://www.mediamarkt.de/

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the price of some items from this site : https://www.mediamarkt.de/

But the usual function ImportXML is not working.

```
=IMPORTXML(https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_apple-iphone-13-128-gb-mitternacht-dual-sim-2764481.html,"//*[@id='StyledPdpWrapper']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[2")
```

Returns #N/A with

```
Error
Could not fetch URL: https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_apple-iphone-13-128-gb-mitternacht-dual-sim-2764481.html
```

I suspect that some anti-scrape system is active but I'm not sure

Is there an alternative way to get the prices?

Comment: Try to add "" in the URL, like this "(https://www.mediamarkt.de/de/product/_apple-iphone-13-128-gb-mitternacht-dual-sim-2764481.html"

Comment: Also, I was reviewing the original Xpath, and it shows as "StyledPdpWrapper" not 'StyledPdpWrapper'. However, if you add "StyledPdpWrapper" as the Xpath, it breaks in Xpath.

Comment: @GiselleValladares I have tried with both of the solutions, enclosing the url within "" and use the xpath with "" and '' both cases give the same error, I have tried to scrape other information, such as the title of the page but it gives the same error.
The only page that I have found where you can scrape something is the homepage

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand your expected values from `I'm trying to get the price of some items from this site : https://www.mediamarkt.de/`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected values?

Comment: Sure @Tanaike, I want to get the price of the item in the page that I have posted. I would like to track the price changes over time and connect such data to a Google Data Studio Dashboard. The expected value in this case would be the price of the iPhone: 
**839.–**

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I check your URL, it seems that in order to retrieve the value of 839, a browser is required to be used. Because in order to retrieve the value, it is required to request the API by including multiple parameters created by Javascript. By this, in this case, I thought that your goal might not be able to be achieved by Google Apps Script. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for your effort, you are right, I supposed that some kind of countermeasure was in place to avoid scraping. I have found a temporary workaround to get the information of prices from another website that tracks e-commerce shops and have a scrapable output, with some REGEX I obtained the same result.
I would like to use a headless browser with RSelenium to try to simulate the requests and verify if with this exploit you can scrape some info.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.